# iOS and Bluetooth HID barcode scanner

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard, barcode-scanner, hid

I have iOS device and Bluetooth barcode scanner, which works as external keyboard.

The task is to get scanned barcode in background mode inside my dynamic library and notify application, which includes my library. All UI stuff is on main app, I cannot insert my code in it, all I have is virtually independent library.

As I think, few approaches might exist:

1. Connect BT scanner by myself and read barcode directly from
           device. I tried to use ExternalAccessory, but EAAccessoryManager
           doesn’t see device. Also there is such stuff as CoreBluetooth for
           BLE, but scanner supports only BT 2.0;
2. Somehow grab HID device
               and exclusively read data from it. I found info about IOHIDFamily,
               but it’s private API, and cannot be used because of AppStore
               requirements;
3. Create some keyboard hook. Catch all keyboard
               events, filter barcode readings and just pass through usual keyboard
               input.

But for now I cannot realize any of my ideas. Maybe someone can help me to do it or suggest any other approach?

Thank you.